# How to add effect inside ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an effect that I normally use like this:

```
<Image.Effect>
   <effects:HueBrightnessContrastSaturationEffect Hue="{Binding hue}"/>
</Image.Effect>
```

Now I need to apply the effect inside the `itemContainerStyle` section. Im trying to add `Effect` as a `Property` but I get ***"Effect" is not recognized or is not accessible***.

Comment: post the xaml you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work fine :

```
<Foo.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <effects:HueBrightnessContrastSaturationEffect Hue="{Binding hue}"/> 
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Foo.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: probably ItemContainerStyle may be not for an Image. perhaps for ListBoxItem, ListViewItem or ContentPresenter etc. It may depend on the parent ItemsControl.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. `ItemContainerStyle` is indeed depends (that's why I put `Foo`), but `Effect` is always for `Image` isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I had to change the TargetType to ContentPresenter. Thanks guys.